# How to count occurrences for each value in MultiMap ? (java)

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, multimap

I have `Multimap`, which contains two strings. Example:

```
1 = [key,car],  
2 = [key,blue],
3 = [key,car]
```

Multimap definition (I am using Guava library):

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> map_multi = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

And this is how I put values in MultiMap:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (i + 1 < list.size()) {

            multimap.put(i,(String) list.get(i));
            multimap.put(i,(String) list.get(i+1));

        } else if (i + 1 == list.size()) {
        }
    }
```

I want to count the occurrences of the same value inside the multimap.

So the result should be 2 if i count how many values `[key,car]` are (per example I have given above) in my multimap:

- occurrences of `[key,car]` = 2
- occurrences of `[key,blue]` = 1

I have also tried to implement this with multi value `HashMap` and I was counting it with this, way (`Storage` is class where I store two string values inside object):

```
B = Collections.frequency(new ArrayList<Storage>(map.values()), map.get(number));
```

But I don't get the right results.

Comment: What look like is your Multipmap definition?

Comment: @ramazankul i have edited my post

Comment: You want to count all different tuples in the multimap? Why not adding them all to a Set and get its size?

Comment: @AntonAdanasjew I want to count same occurances, not how many different tuples are in MultiMap. :)

Comment: As your question is a little vague, it would be helpful if you would show the desired output for your example as well.

Comment: @Lauri i have edited it, i hope it is more understandable

Comment: @booyah Then you can produce a stream from the resulting set and use the groupingBy collector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by creating a map that has your multimap values as the keys and the count as the value:

```
Map<Collection<String>, Long> result = map_multi.asMap().values().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v, Collectors.counting()));
```

Here I've used Guava's [`Multimap.asMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap--) method to get a *view* over the original multimap, then collected the values into a new map.

Another way, without streams:

```
Map<Collection<String>, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
map_multi.asMap().values().forEach(v -> result.merge(v, 1, Integer::sum));
```

This uses the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method to accumulate equal values by counting its occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. `map_multi.get(key).size()` is your answer.

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> map_multi = ArrayListMultimap.create();
map_multi.put(1, "car");
map_multi.put(2, "blue");
map_multi.put(3, "apple");
map_multi.put(1, "car");

for (Integer key : map_multi.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(map_multi.get(key).get(0) + " occurances: " + map_multi.get(key).size());
}
```

Output:

```
car occurances: 2
blue occurances: 1
apple occurances: 1
```

Comment: @Schidu Luca yes, i need to compare two strings (value of multimap entry) which are stored under same key, with another valuea under same key, so this answer is not quite the solution i am looking for, in this case we are looking for only one string and comparing it

Comment: You said in your question : "I want to count the occurances of the same value inside the Multimap". when you do "map_multi.get(key)", you get all values with connected this key. After this you can compare all value witch each other.

Comment: @ramazankul hmm i will check this out

Comment: @ramazankul i think this is only counting number of values under one key, not quite what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

So the first step is to create a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` from your `ListMultimap`. You can do this in the following way:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> collect = map_multi.entries()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                     Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                        Collectors.toList())));
```

Then let's say you have a `List<String>` with `car` and `key` in it.
 Example:

```
 List<String> myList = List.of("key", "car"); // java 9
```

You just iterate through the `values()` of the map and check if `myList` contains all elements from map's lists.

```
long count = collect.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(list -> list.containsAll(myList))
            .count();
```

Comment: I think this is the solution. But as i am reading this wouldn't be easier to implement Map in first place, instead of converting it. This should give me the same result right ? @Schidu Luca

Comment: Whole first transformation is built-in feature of `ListMutlimap`: use [`Multimap#asMap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html#asMap--) (to get `Map<Integer, Collection<String>>` view) or [`Multimaps#asMap(ListMultimap)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#asMap-com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap-) (to get type-coerced `Map<Integer, List<String>>` view).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using wrong collection to store your data. Based on what you wrote, you want a map with integer keys and two-element tuples as values and then use [`Multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) to count frequencies:

> *`Multiset` is* a collection that supports order-independent equality, like `Set`, but may have duplicate elements. A multiset is also sometimes called a *bag*.
>
> Elements of a multiset that are equal to one another are referred to as occurrences of the same single element. **The total number of occurrences of an element in a multiset is called the count of that element (the terms "frequency" and "multiplicity" are equivalent**, but not used in this API).

The code below assumes you have proper implementation of two-element tuple (aka pair, or your `Storage` class, but with proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementations), like [this one from jOOL](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.12/org/jooq/lambda/tuple/Tuple2.html):

```
HashMap<Integer, Tuple2<String, String>> m = new HashMap<>();
Tuple2<String, String> carTuple = new Tuple2<>("key", "car");
Tuple2<String, String> blueTuple = new Tuple2<>("key", "blue");

m.put(1, carTuple);
m.put(2, blueTuple);
m.put(3, carTuple);

ImmutableMultiset<Tuple2<String, String>> occurrences = 
    ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(m.values());
System.out.println(occurrences); // [(key, car) x 2, (key, blue)]
```

*If* you need to have few values (tuples) mapped under one key (integer), then you should change the first line to multimap:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Tuple2<String, String>> m = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

so that `m.put(1, anotherTuple)` is possible and putting doesn't override first value (`carTuple`) but rather adds it under `1` values list.

***EDIT:***

You can implement `Tuple2` yourself if you don't need/want additional dependency, it could look like this class:

```
public class Tuple2<T1, T2> {

  public final T1 v1;
  public final T2 v2;

  public Tuple2(T1 v1, T2 v2) {
    this.v1 = v1;
    this.v2 = v2;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Tuple2)) {
      return false;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"}) final Tuple2<T1, T2> that = (Tuple2) o;
    return Objects.equals(v1, that.v1) && Objects.equals(v2, that.v2);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(v1, v2);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "(" + v1 + ", " + v2 + ")";
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this should to the trick, but i have a noobies problem. I don't know how to import jooq to Netbeans :(

Comment: You don't really have to use jOOL, you can write the class yourself (similarly to your `Storage`) - again, all it needs is proper `hashCode` and `equals` implementation. I've edited answer.